# Asp.net how to allow client open file in localhost?

Tags: asp.net, file, windows-7, lan

I'm very new to asp.net and also networking. May be this question sound a bit dummy to you. I'm having asp.net project. This is not about internet it's only in LAN. I just want to let client open a file in server directly. It's like share folder in Window 7 I can just go to that share folder and open that file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via IIS 7 directory browsing feature.

Take a look 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx